# PHP Session Unsetting in Gecko/Webkit

Tags: php, firefox, session, google-chrome

I have a PHP Session variable set:

`$_SESSION['token']=$_POST['token'];` on `newOrder.php`.

Also set is `$_SESSION['orderId']`, `$_SESSION['stylesUrl']`, `$_SESSION['brand']` and `$_SESSION['currentBalance']`

There is a link on `newOrder.php` to `templateSelection.php` (same server).

At the bottom of `newOrder.php` I do a `print_r($_SESSION)` with the following output:

```
[token] => {61424637-6E77-BCE0-A10B-3F3E9F74753E}
[currentBalance] => 991.0000
[stylesUrl] => /Management/Stylesheets/basic.css
[brand] => YM
[savedOrderReturnURL] => /Management/DirectMail/DirectMailSaveOrder.aspx
```

This is directly at the bottom of the `newOrder.php` page with just two lines of HTML afterwards. When a user clicks a link to `templateSelection.php` the following php is processed:

```
<?php include("php/db.php");
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"');
//$_SESSION['username']="bymtest";
//We seem to be getting an orderId in the session variable even though there wasn't one just before this page was called.
$debugMode = true;
if($debugMode) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
}
```

Inside `php/db.php` is:

```
$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'un';
$dbpass = 'pw';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
$db = mysql_select_db("db");
session_start();
```

Now this is the weird part. In firefox and chrome, the `print_r` in `templateSelection.php` outputs:

```
[token] => 
[currentBalance] => 991.0000
[stylesUrl] => /Stylesheets/basic.css
[brand] => YM
[savedOrderReturnURL] => /Management/DirectMail/DirectMailSaveOrder.aspx
```

However in Opera and IE9/8/7/6 it outputs

```
[token] => {61424637-6E77-BCE0-A10B-3F3E9F74753E}
[currentBalance] => 991.0000
[stylesUrl] => /Management/Stylesheets/basic.css
[brand] => YM
[savedOrderReturnURL] => /Management/DirectMail/DirectMailSaveOrder.aspx
```

`session_start` is always set, I have tried on multiple computers... it just makes no sense! This has also worked before on a different URL, on the same server.

Comment: Try `echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_SESSION, true));`. Just in case. And do the same on the `$_POST` array on the page where you set the session values.

Comment: Check the source of the page in firefox, it should be there normally!

Comment: @hakre thanks, output is still the same on `templateSelection.php` (blank). `newOrder.php` provides the same output as before, and the value for post is identical: `[token] => {61424637-6E77-BCE0-A10B-3F3E9F74753E}`

Comment: I suggest having `session_start()` as first function called during PHP execution, always.

Comment: @Griwes, moved to top but no difference (also tested it at the top of templateSelection.php as opposed to php/db.php)

Comment: God knows what the effing problem was but it appears to of resolved itself after 2 fricking hours of not working.

Comment: If at the end of `newOrder.php` `$_SESSION` still contained all values, you need to verify (before opening `templateSelection.php`), that the value has been actually saved into the session file on disk with a session file viewer, here is one: https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized/blob/master/examples/03-session/example-viewer.php

Comment: Thanks any way @hakre, the issues resolved itself.

Comment: As long as it does not un-resolve itself again suddenly... :) 2 hours? GMT offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Griwes suggests, you need to call `session_start()` at the top of your script.